# How to change "SAS Output" in web-browser tab with ODS HTML command?

Tags: sas

I output the results to HTML using a command like this:

```
proc import out=DATASET
    datafile="DATASET.csv"
    dbms=csv replace;
run;

ods html body='html_page.htm' style=HTMLBlue;


proc means data=teeth ;
run;


ods html close;
```

When I view `html_page.htm` in a web-browser, the tab is labeled "SAS Output".  If I look at the source code of `html_page.htm` I see that this is under the tag `<TITLE> SAS Output </TITLE>`.  So I tried the following command but it didn't work:

```
ods html title=`NEW TAB TITLE` body='html_page.htm' style=HTMLBlue;


proc means data=teeth ;
run;


ods html close;
```

How can I change the tab title with and ODS HTML command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the page title in the sub-options of ODS HTML BODY option.

```
ods html body='html_page.htm'(title="My Title") style=HTMLBlue;
```